# R ggplot encoding/locale issue with ssh -X

Tags: r, ssh, ggplot2

[ This is a cross posting to the R-help mailing list [post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/339287) where this question has remained unanswered so far ]

I am struggling with remote R sessions and a (I suspect) locale related
encoding problem:  Using the `X11` device (X11forwarding enabled),
whenever I try to plot something containing umlauts using `ggplot2`, I am
seeing sth like

```
Error in grid.Call(L_stringMetric, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)) :
  invalid use of -61 < 0 in 'X11_MetricInfo'
```

Using base graphics is fine as is plotting to another device (pdf, say).

Here is some code to reproduce:

```
## ssh -X into the remote server
## start R at the remote server

plot(1:10, 1:10, main = "größe")
## this opens a plot window and works as expected

library("ggplot2")
qplot(1:10, 1:10)
## this works still

qplot(1:10, 1:10) + xlab("größe")
## I get the ERROR above
```

My setup:

- locally:
  Linux (Debian GNU/Linux 9)
- remotely
  Linux (RHEL Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

(Maybe) relevant bits of my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host theserver
     HostName XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
     ForwardX11 yes
     ForwardX11Timeout 596h
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
     IdentitiesOnly yes
     ForwardAgent yes
     ServerAliveInterval 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of R do you have (on the remote machine)?

I can replicate this with:

```
x11(type="Xlib")
library(grid)
convertHeight(stringDescent("größe"), "in")
```

on R 3.2.5, but not on, e.g., R 3.4.0 (just running R locally in
both cases).

Comment: Right on spot. It used to be `R version 3.3.1`.  I updated to `R version 3.4.0`. Now everything seems to work! Thanks!